# Does the smaller shiny area also need thermal paste in this kind of CPU?

Tags: laptop, cpu, cooling, thermal-paste

My laptop has i7 8550U CPU.

As you can see in following photo (found on YouTube), there are 2 shiny areas on processor *(highlighted by yellow arrows)*.

[image]

I found a clearer image of same CPU so you can easily see there are two shiny parts:

[image]

Now, I'm pretty sure the bigger area needs thermal paste. I saw the same on YouTube when people were disassembling it.

But I'm not sure about the smaller area. It doesn't look like there was any thermal paste applied on it.

But what made me curious is when I found many other videos about similar laptop processors, where people were putting thermal paste (replacing old thermal paste) on both the areas. The smaller as well as the main/bigger one.

So I think either the smaller area needs the thermal paste or it doesn't need for some technical reason.

That is what I'm trying to find out.

**Does it need thermal paste?**

Comment: Does the heatsink cover both ICs?

Comment: You need thermal paste between the CPU and the Fan Housing at the point of contact. If both are covered, you need paste on both points. If only one is contacted, that is the one that needs paste. Did the thermal paste fail?  Why are you needing to do this?

Comment: I doubt the manufacturer would waste copper unless necessary, because it's the most expensive material in the heatsink.

Sometimes there's a thermal pad instead. If there was no pad, the paste will help ensure there's a seal with good contact. Chips can burn up in a few seconds without proper contact. ‍

Comment: @Ramhound yes. I haven't opened mine so far. But in the YouTube video (same laptop) I could see it covered both shiny parts of processor (I guess those are called ICs).

Comment: @John last time I got my laptop repaired (basically they replaced keyboard), the technician had to remove each part of my laptop. Including that heatsink. I didn't pay attention at that time but when he put the heatsink again, he didn't apply new thermal paste again. I want to apply it again manually. I feel that has made my laptop slow. It is slower than before.

Comment: @LouisWaweru BTW aren't laptops/desktops CPUs designed to auto shutdown automatically in case of overheating?

Comment: Yep, that’s right but not until until later iterations of x86 in Intel’s case, and this is more of a mechanical feature than something truly reliable and innate. Also, I can’t say I’ve heard of this outside of CPU design. GPUs began throttling down more recently, but the total shutdown that happens when you’re installing a CPU and forget the heatsink, or install it improperly, might not be even be a design consideration because of how they’re package for end-use. Not sure, but have definitely seen burnt out GPUs from normal operation (and GPUs taking out PSUs).

Comment: @LouisWaweru anyway I just spend 3 hours and replaced the paste. When I removed the heatsink, I could see only the bigger IC with grey paste. The smaller one was still shiny like there was no paste. I didn't touch it at all. I just removed the paste from bigger IC and pasted new thermal paste there.

Comment: HOWEVER, when I looked at copper heatsink, on one side of it was same grey paste, and the other side had a copper colored paste like rectangular thing. I think it was also some kind of thermal paste for the smaller portion IC of the CPU. I did not remove it. I just cleaned the grey paste from both CPU and heatsink and replaced it.

Comment: Then I tried to start my PC. Daym! The OS was probably corrupted for some reason. Maybe some power issues when I removed battery. I tought I messed some hardware. Then I installed a fresh Windows 10 again. And it's working fine since last 1 hour.

Comment: Hope I didn't mess up any hardware. It was just software problem.

Comment: @John I would like you too to read my above comments. Hope it will clarify those IC and thermal paste things?

Comment: Yes. I read the comments. If the housing touches both areas you need paste on both areas.

Comment: @John yeah. I had also taken a photo. You can see a grey and a copper colored paste. I left copper color paste as it is. Didn't remove because it looked fine to me also I didn't have this kind of paste. So just cleaned grey side. https://imgur.com/TsQ2tmx

Comment: BTW I have got enough confidence now after my first experience. My fear is gone.